# Laravel multiple counts with condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, count, eloquent

I'm tring to retrieve the totals of items from a table but can't get my head around it.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

I have a table 'users' with the following columns:

- Admin - yes/no
- Moderator - yes/no

I am trying to retrieve the total of the items in the table but also the total of items in the table with admin = 'yes' OR moderator = 'yes'. The reason for this is to display the totals in one table.

Below is my sample code:

```
    $date = new DateTime('tomorrow -360 month');

    $usersPerDay = User::select(array(
        DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'),
```

> this is where I have the problem - Is it possible to do something like
>   this

```
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "type" WHERE admin= "yes" OR moderator= "yes"')

    ))
    ->where('created_at', '>', $date)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: You've got a syntax error: `'COUNT(*) as 'type' ... ` No closing `'` (single quote); may want to use `"` or escaping `\'` in your `DB::raw()` statement.

Comment: @TimLewis.. Thanx for the headup. That was a type from making the post. The problem persist. Any further help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might help to use Laravel's DB query log to see exactly what query is actually getting executed?

Comment: Instead of using multiple `DB::raw()` statements, just use a single `selectRaw()`, so something like `User::selectRaw('COUNT(*) AS "type", ...)->orderBy(...)->get();`

Comment: Why don't you put the where admin or moderator into the ->wheres below?

Comment: @chasenyc if I do that, the query will only return records that match those criteria, and I want to also get a total of all records plus the total of those that match the "where"

Comment: Thanx everyone for your various response. I finally solved my problem using the following code:

    $userPerDay = Users::select(array(
            DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`) as `date`'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'),
            DB::raw(
            "SUM(CASE
                WHEN admin = 'yes' OR moderator = 'yes'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'admin_moderator'"
         )
         ))
        ->where('created_at', '>', $date)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();